# How to merge two lists to find minimal repetition factor?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**I have two lists for example**

```
A = ["spin", "dab", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
B = ["dab", "dab", "spin", "clap", "clap", "moonwalk"]
```

**After merging two lists, i could have a list like this**

```
remix=["dab", "spin", "dab", "spin", "dab", "clap", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
```

My question is that how to merge two lists so that the the adjacent repetition of elements is minimal(All the elements in A and B must appear in the remix list).
the repetition is something like this

```
remix=["spin", "dab", "spin", "dab", "dab", "clap", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
```

the adjacent repetition here is 2*dab

**Another example is**

```
remix=["spin", "dab", "spin", "dab", "dab", "clap", "clap","dab", "moonwalk", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
```

the adjacent repetition is 2*dab+2*clap

**below is the the input for this question**

```
A = ["spin", "dab", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
B = ["dab", "dab", "spin", "clap", "clap", "moonwalk"]
factor={"spin":1,"dab":2,"moonwalk":3,"clap":4}
```

output list:

```
["dab", "spin", "dab", "spin", "dab", "clap", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
```

**The reason is that there is no repetition so the adjacent repetition of any element is 0.
Again the goal is to find the list with minimal adjacent repetition, of course the factor could be 0 if we could find a list without repetition at all**

I was thinking about Dynamic programming, but i have no idea how to make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `A + B` to combine list `A` and `B`

Comment: So you want to merge the list to minimize **adjacent** repetition? Is that right? `dab, dab, clap` is a repetition, but `spin, dab, spin` isn't?

Comment: The goal is to find minimal repetition factor. If there is no repetition then that is  the best solution, otherwise output the list with minimal repetition factor

Comment: @Mark Meyer  exactly.

Comment: Ok, the only remaining item I'm not quite understanding is how is the `factor` dictionary used here?

Comment: every element in the input list has it own factor, for example spin is 1, dab is 2, if we finally get a list like this [dab,dab,spin, spin] the factor of this list should be 2*2+1*2=6

Comment: Can you reorder after merging?

Comment: I don't think that gives you any sort of minimization capability, since all you are doing is effectively adding: `2 + 2 + 1 + 1` is exactly the same as `2 + 1 + 2 + 1`, so even though in the latter case you have reduced adjacent repetition, the commutative nature of your operation won't show the benefit

Comment: Please edit your attempt to code this into your question. Come on, you must have tried something.

Comment: yes, the strategy here is to reorder them to find the optimal solution with minimal repetition factor. @gmds

Comment: @C.Nivs  If it is not adjacent repetition, then we don't calculate it's factor. We only calculate the repetition factor

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure with your expected output. Do you mean something like this?

```
import random
A = ["spin", "dab", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk"]
B = ["dab", "dab", "spin", "clap", "clap", "moonwalk"]

AB = A + B
elem = AB
while elem != []:
    random.shuffle(AB)
    elem = []
    for i in range(len(AB)-1):
        if AB[i] == AB[i+1]:
            elem.append([AB[i],AB[i+1]])
    print (AB)
    print (elem)
    print ("Repetition factor: ")
    for e in elem:
        print(str(len(e)) + "*" + e[0])
    print ("\n")
```

Output:

```
['spin', 'moonwalk', 'dab', 'dab', 'spin', 'dab', 'moonwalk', 'moonwalk', 'clap', 'clap', 'dab', 'clap']
[['dab', 'dab'], ['moonwalk', 'moonwalk'], ['clap', 'clap']]
Repetition factor: 
2*dab
2*moonwalk
2*clap

['spin', 'dab', 'clap', 'dab', 'moonwalk', 'dab', 'dab', 'clap', 'moonwalk', 'clap', 'moonwalk', 'spin']
[['dab', 'dab']]
Repetition factor: 
2*dab

['moonwalk', 'dab', 'clap', 'moonwalk', 'clap', 'dab', 'spin', 'dab', 'moonwalk', 'clap', 'dab', 'spin']
[]
Repetition factor:
```

Comment: thx for you reply, but your answer seems to fail to calculate the factor of the output list. for example  ["spin", "dab", "dab", "moonwalk", "clap", "moonwalk","dab", "dab", "spin", "clap", "clap", "moonwalk"], the factor should be 2*dab+2*dad but i am not sure if this is the minimal factor of all the possible output lists

Comment: Updated. See if it helps

Comment: why down vote? Suggest me if there's something to improve

Comment: Thx again, yes this could be a way to work it out. But your algorithm is that find all the possible lists randomly and calculate the minimal which could not yield the best solution and could cost much time if the input is huge

Comment: Yes, you're right. The drawback is take much time if you have large data.